# PureComponent in React this 'undefined' not the class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I change the keyword this in React PureComponent

```
class MyComponent extends PureComponent {
    handleClick = () => { console.log(this); }
    render() {
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>CLICK</button>
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain it better? A possible solution is to use function instead of class to remove the this keyword

Comment: The render function doesn't return anything. If that is added, this example does not throw any errors and successfully renders a button.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What do you mean by _"how can I change the keyword this"_? Change it to what? Why?